# Is there any tool to read Kafka messages filter them by content?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a lot of topics with huge replication value. Currently, I'm using for that kafdrop but need something better for reading messages. So my question is there any tool to read Kafka messages filter them by content?

Comment: Asking for tools is off topic - from [help]

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [offset explorer](https://www.kafkatool.com/download.html) which can help you. It has filter functionality at the messages level. This one is free

Other good is [kadeck](https://getkadeck.com/) . This one you can try for 7/15 days for free. Its faster than offset explorer but not free